# Sharepoint Custom List with TimeStamp Field

Tags: sharepoint

I'm making a custom SharePoint List. I need a TimeStamp Field, but the only available type, by default, is DateTime.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to create a custom field type so that you can control the display of a DateTime type and validation etc - see [this blog post](http://www.sharethispoint.com/archive/2006/08/07/23.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Sharepoint 2010 and solved it. Posting in case someone else finds this useful :)

To achieve this one must use the "Calculated" columntype.

**From GUI:**

1. Create new column
2. Pick type "Calculated".
3. Select "Created" column and add to formula.
4. Save.

**From code:**

As far as I can tell, there is two options to achieve this:

1. Access the "Created" and either set it's ShowInDisplayForm property to true or add the column to a view (for example the DefaultView).
2. Create a calculated column that points to the "Created" column, just as the GUI-example does. The trick is to set the "Formula" & the "OutputType" properties.

   ```
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {
       using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
       {
           using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
           {
               SPList list = web.Lists["test"];
               string fieldName = list.Fields.Add("Timestamptest", SPFieldType.Calculated, false);
               SPFieldCalculated field = list.Fields[fieldName] as SPFieldCalculated;
               field.Formula = "=Created";
               field.OutputType = SPFieldType.DateTime;
               field.ShowInEditForm = false;
               field.Update();
               list.Update();
               SPView defaultView = list.DefaultView;
               defaultView.ViewFields.Add(field);
               defaultView.Update();
           }
       }
   });
   ```